# volume group not found on linux laptop after update

Tags: luks, nvme

After a recent update (not sure if that was the first including a new kernel 6.1) my ubuntu linux laptop cannot boot anymore

the error is

```
Volume group “ubuntu-vg” not found
Cannot process volume group ubuntu vg
IO error while decrypting keyslot.
Keyslot open failed.
Device /dev/nvme0n1p3 does not exist or access is denied

Please unlock disk nvme0n1p3_crypt_
```

but then the usual decrypting code does not work

while in initram shell I noticed there were
no device /dev/nvme* nor /dev/mappe* for my internal ssd

I managed to boot the laptop with a  ubuntu live usb stick
and manually decrypted and mounted my ssd partitions and my data were all there

so I rebooted then I made the grub boot menu to appear again and I selected the previous kernel 5.17, and the system managed to boot normally

Now I would like to fix the new kernel in a stable way

here are some info on my laptop:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64 
Host: XPS 15 9560 
Kernel: 5.17.0-1035-oem
```

my boot partition content is

```
$ ll /boot/ | grep -E "initrd|vmlinuz"
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        25 2023-10-05 20:38:05 initrd.img -> initrd.img-6.1.0-1023-oem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 112483877 2023-10-16 03:12:30 initrd.img-5.15.0-86-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 117815613 2023-10-16 03:12:18 initrd.img-5.17.0-1035-oem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 130800464 2023-10-16 03:12:06 initrd.img-6.1.0-1023-oem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        28 2023-10-05 20:38:05 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.15.0-86-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        22 2023-10-05 20:38:05 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-6.1.0-1023-oem
-rw------- 1 root root  11624584 2023-09-20 10:09:11 vmlinuz-5.15.0-86-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  11275528 2023-07-12 11:49:08 vmlinuz-5.17.0-1035-oem
-rw------- 1 root root  12521608 2023-09-15 14:50:36 vmlinuz-6.1.0-1023-oem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        25 2023-10-05 20:38:05 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.15.0-86-generic
$
```

the lsblk for nvme

```
$ lsblk  | tail -n 7
nvme0n1                 259:0    0 476,9G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1             259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2             259:2    0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3             259:3    0 475,7G  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt     253:0    0 475,7G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   253:1    0 474,8G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:2    0   980M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
$
```

the fstab

```
$ cat /etc/fstab | grep -E "mount point|^/"
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
$
```

I have read a post of similar issues on another XPS laptop - i.e.:

```
$  lspci | grep Unassigned
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
$
```

Should/could  I also blacklist the drivers

```
blacklist rtsx_pci
blacklist rtsx_pci_sdmmc
```

in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_rtsx.conf and rebuild the initramfs?

I am asking since I am quite worried to brick the system

Apologies if I used terminology incorrectly or asked dumb questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately adding `nve` and `lvm` to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` ,
updating initramfs and rebooting
was not effective.
Thus I reverted that change and then I tried adding

```
blacklist rtsx_pci
blacklist rtsx_pci_sdmmc
```

to (a new) file
`/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_rtsx.conf`
and rebooting
and the problem was solved

(then I have read that a patch for this has been already been submitted
to the kernel maintainers, so chances are this issue
may soon become a thing of the past)

Answer (score 0):

> while in initram shell I noticed there were no device /dev/nvme* nor /dev/mappe* for my internal ssd

This suggests that the kernel didn't have the nvme module loaded.

This might help:

- add `nvme` and `lvm` to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`
- rebuild the initramfs: `update-initramfs -u -k all`
- reboot